# Sort ps output by the command in Solaris

Tags: process, command, sort, ps, reboot

The purpose of this exercise is to dump the output of `ps` sorted by command.

While the system is running we wish to dump all the running process sorted by command in a file.

There is a sort option in Linux like below.

```
ps -ef --sort -comm | grep -v grep | grep java > /tmp/preboot.log
```

After the server reboots and all the processes started afresh I wish to again dump the output like below.

```
ps -ef --sort -comm | grep -v grep | grep java > /tmp/postboot.log
```

Using `diff /tmp/preboot.log /tmp/postboot.log` we can be sure that all processes have been started alright is no difference is found..

The above works in Linux and does not work in Solaris.

Please suggest any solution for my requirement of pre & post reboot check for the process for Solaris.

Comment: What part of it doesn't work?  Also don't you have to `grep -v grep` **after** the grep for java?  But you could also just `grep [j]ava` to avoid that altogether.

Comment: Solaris doesn't have gnu tools so the --sort option will not be available.  You could probably just pipe to sort instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Solaris have it, and if have it how it behave, but on linux `sort` command work.

You can use `sort` command like this:

```
# With ps --sort
ps U $USER -o comm,pid --sort pid | head -n1
systemd 2120

# With sort cmd
ps U $USER -o comm,pid | sort -k2 | head -n1
systemd 2120
```

In my linux box it work.

i can't test on solaris

Comment: does not work on solaris. Output: `$ ps U $USER -o comm,pid | sort -k2 | head -n1
ps: too many arguments
usage: ps [ -aceglnrSuUvwx ] [ -t term ] [ num ]`

Comment: Of course, is just an example. The key point is that if you have `sort` cmd on your solaris you can use it without call sort function of `ps`. Use somthing like: `ps -ef  -comm | grep -v grep | sort` Be sure to use sort on the desired column